# Question about function of two variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

The function is:

$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
xy^3 \sin \left(\frac{1}{{x^4+y^4}}\right), & \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
0, & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}.$$

I have to check if it is of class $C^1$.

I've found that

$d_xf(0,0) = 0$

and

$d_{y} f(0,0) = 0$

I know how to prove by definition it's differentiable at the origin and obviously it's differentiable elsewhere.
But I don't know how to prove that partial derivatives are/are not continuous.
For example i get

$d_xf(x,y) = y^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^4+y^4}\right) - \frac{(4x^4y^3)\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4+y^4}\right)}{(x^4+y^4)^2}$

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $f_x(0,0)=0$ but $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,y) \neq 0$ indeed for $x=y=t \to 0$

$$f_x(x,y)= y^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^4+y^4}\right) - \frac{(4x^4y^3)\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^4+y^4}\right)}{(x^4+y^4)^2}=t^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{2t^4}\right) - \frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{2t^4}\right)}{t}$$

with $t^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{2t^4}\right)\to 0$ but $\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{2t^4}\right)}{t}$ clearly doesn't admit a limit.

To show that let consider for example $\frac{1}{2t_n^4}=2\pi n \implies t_n=\frac1{\sqrt [4]{4\pi n}} $ such that

$$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{2t_n^4}\right)}{t_n}=\sqrt [4]{4\pi n} \to \infty$$

Therefore the function is not of class $C^1$.

Comment: I've proven that the function is differentiable at the origin without polar coordinates, since the denominator is greater than or equal to the absolute value of h

Comment: Yes of course the limit can be proved also by inequality

Comment: You can also see why partial derivatives are not continuous, the second term is problematic at the origin.

Comment: Could you prove that the limit of the second term at the origin is not zero?

Comment: If we take the path $x=y$?

Comment: You should edit your answer so that it actually answers the question the OP posed.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I’ll edit it. Thanks